# Can I set a value to a range of index of an array without using loops?

Tags: arrays, stl

Like if `a[7]={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}`
Is there any easy solution or function to set a range of elements to another value?
For example,

for the array a[7] up there, I want to make elements 0 from index 2 to index 5.
then the array will be,

```
a[7]={1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7}
```

How can i do it without using any loops?

Is there any STL function or something else like that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for

```
std::fill(a+2, a+6, 0);
```